# Is there any general reference on matrix quadratic equations?

Tags: matrix-equations

I am studying a problem where a quadratic matrix equation emerges. The equation is as follow (all capital letters are n by n matrices)

$(I-X^{\prime}L)X=D$

where $L$ and $D$ are both symmetric and positive definite. How much can I say about a solution $X$?

Comment: Assuming you're using $'$ for transpose, it's symmetric.

Comment: Yes, $\prime$ for transpose. Could there be any sufficient and necessary conditions that guarantee the existence of a solution?

Comment: Did you try the case of $2\times 2$-matrices? And why do you think the question has an easy to formulate answer?

Comment: I don't presume this would be easy but wonder if there could be any results about the existence of a solution. I am not familiar with matrix equations. In the case of 2 by 2, this would be a system of quadratic equations and may be reduced to a quartic equation.

Comment: You write in your answer that "in the original equation $X$ must be symmetric", but this is not stated in your question, and on the contrary you used $X'$ there which suggests that there is a difference between the two. Is $X$ symmetric or not? If the answer is yes, then this is equation is well studied (algebraic Riccati equation; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/345456/1898)).

Comment: Also, your title is a lot more general than your actual question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a quadratic matrix equation with positive semidefinite constaint](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345456/how-to-solve-a-quadratic-matrix-equation-with-positive-semidefinite-constaint) Not an exact duplicate (different definiteness assumptions) but things work in the same way and my solution applies.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni $X = D + X^T L X$ must be symmetric, so the original equation might as well assume it.

Answer (score 2):

A good resource is : Abou-Kandil, Hisham, Gerhard Freiling, Vlad Ionescu, and Gerhard Jank. Matrix Riccati equations in control and systems theory. Birkhäuser, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out something and would like to share and check whether it is correct.

It is perfectly analogous to real quadratic equations.

Since $L$ is symmetric and positive definite, they can be decomposed:

$L=U_L^{\prime} \Lambda_L U_L$ where $U_L$ is orthonormal, and $\Lambda_L$ is diagonal with positive entries.

Let $Q=U_L^{\prime} \Lambda_L^{-1/2} U_L$, which is the inverse of the square root of $L$, and it is symmetric.

Then the above equation is equivalent to

$\tilde{X}^{\prime} \tilde{X}-Q\tilde{X}=D$ where $\tilde{X}=Q^{-1}X$

Suppose, in addition, $D$ and $L$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, I conjecture that $\tilde{X}$ is symmetric. Therefore, the above is equivalent to

$(\tilde{X}-\frac{1}{2}Q)^{\prime}(\tilde{X}-\frac{1}{2}Q)=\frac{1}{4}L^{-1}-D$

Note that the right-hand side is symmetric; hence, there exists a real solution of $\tilde{X}$ if and only if the right-hand side is positive semi-definite.

And after a bit of algebra, if solutions exist, it would be

$X=\frac{1}{2}L^{-1}[I \pm (I-4LD)^{1/2}]$ where $(I-4LD)^{1/2}$ is the real p.s.d square root of $(I-4LD)$, which exists because $(I-4LD)^{1/2}$ is p.s.d. and symmetric.

Hence, there are at most two solutions.

Are all of these arguments correct?

Comment: I don't see why $X$ symmetric implies $\tilde{X}$ symmetric. A product of symmetric matrices is not symmetric.

Comment: You are right, I just notice that and add some assumption. @Federico Poloni

Comment: $X$ is symmetric because $X=D+X^{\prime}LX$ where the right-hand side is symmetric given that $L$ and $D$ is symmetric.

Comment: I see, thanks. Then I suggest you to take a look at the question I linked in the comment above. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I definitely will. Thank you. @Federico Poloni